# PostgreSQL 9.4 - Comparing NULL values

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-9.4

Under normal conditions, comparing a `NULL` value to any other value results in another `NULL` value.

```
SELECT NULL = NULL;
```

**Returns `NULL`**

---

This holds (mostly) true when comparing arbitrary rows, as explained in [the documentation, 9.23.5. Row Constructor Comparison](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/functions-comparisons.html):

```
SELECT ROW(1, NULL, 'baz text') = ROW(1, NULL, 'baz text');
```

**Returns `NULL`**

---

However, when comparing well defined composite types, `NULL` values are treated as equal.

```
CREATE TYPE test_type AS (
    foo INTEGER,
    bar BIGINT,
    baz TEXT
);

SELECT (1, NULL, 'baz text')::test_type = (1, NULL, 'baz text')::test_type;
```

**Returns `TRUE`**

This behavior seems to be undocumented (I have looked and found no reference to the behavior).

I would like to use this behavior to implement some business rules and want to make sure it is safe to do so.

1. Is this consistent with any SQL specification?
2. Is it *likely* this will change in the future?

Comment: For stable results you could always use: `SELECT ROW(1, NULL, 'baz text') IS NOT DISTINCT FROM ROW(1, NULL, 'baz text'); `

Comment: @lad2025 - I'm familiar with the `IS NOT DISTINCT FROM` clause; however, **I'm interested in the `=` operator when used with composite types**.

Comment: This is interesting, I guess it compares string representation **[Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!15/9eecb7db59d16c80417c72d1e1f4fbf1/5221/1)**. So `{ "type": "test_type", "value": "(,,)" }={ "type": "test_type", "value": "(,,)" }` => true

Comment: @lad2025 - wow... your second test `(NULL,NULL, NULL)::test_type IS NULL` **Returns `TRUE`** - I find that even more interesting as `SELECT ARRAY[NULL] IS NULL` **Returns `FALSE`** (not relevant to this question, just interesting).

Comment: This is described in [doc](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/functions-comparison.html) `If the expression is row-valued, then IS NULL is true when the row expression itself is null or when all the row's fields are null, while IS NOT NULL is true when the row expression itself is non-null and all the row's fields are non-null.`

Comment: If this isn't mentioned in the documentation, I'd file a bug.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I found this in the [official documentation](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/functions-comparisons.html): *[...] In other contexts where two composite-type values are compared, two NULL field values are considered equal, and a NULL is considered larger than a non-NULL. This is necessary in order to have consistent sorting and indexing behavior for composite types.*. I think this resolves your question.

Answer (score 0):

Illustration (sorry, I cannot do this in a comment, need the formatting):

```
CREATE TYPE test_type AS (
    foo INTEGER
    , bar BIGINT
    , baz TEXT
    );

        -- plain table with three fields
CREATE TABLE test_table0 (
    foo INTEGER
    , bar BIGINT
    , baz TEXT
    );

        -- the same, but with a composite type
CREATE TABLE test_table1 (
        tt test_type
        );

INSERT INTO test_table0 (foo,bar,baz)
        VALUES (1, NULL, 'baz text');

INSERT INTO test_table1 (tt)
        VALUES( (1, NULL, 'baz text')::test_type) ;

        -- union needs a "whole row" -compare
SELECT * FROM test_table0
UNION
SELECT * FROM test_table0
        ;

        -- union needs a "whole row" -compare
        -- and type needs a whole "composite" compare
SELECT * FROM test_table1
UNION
SELECT * FROM test_table1
        ;
```

---

Result:

```
CREATE TYPE
CREATE TABLE
CREATE TABLE
INSERT 0 1
INSERT 0 1
 foo | bar |   baz    
-----+-----+----------
   1 |     | baz text
(1 row)

       tt        
-----------------
 (1,,"baz text")
(1 row)
```

---

- Note: the **objects** that are compared (type instances and tuples) are not NULL, only some of their elements.
- I do *think* this is the intended behaviour
- IMHO this comes close to the problem with allowing NULL elements in composite keys, (see the rants by Chris Date about this)
- probably the other behaviour would lead to even stranger artefacts

Comment: I see what you are doing, but I'm not sure I understand it's implications... do you have any input on if this behavior should be trusted today, and also in the future?

Comment: At least the `UNION` construct relies on the comparison of whole rows, even if there are NULLs in there. And yes: some people rely on UNIONs to work as shown.